# Fullscreen image on different iOS iPhone sizes

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcasset

I am not ignorant of how many questions exist around the topic, I've read most and haven't been able to find a straight answer to what should be a common thing to do.

**How does one handle full screen sized images on on different phone sizes?**

Current strategy:

I'm using vectors so the idea is to create 3 vectors (PDF) in 3 different image assets:

- **Name**: mypicture-320  **Size**: 320 x 568
- **Name**: mypicture-375  **Size**: 375 x 667
- **Name**: mypicture-414  **Size**: 414 x 736

Then when I want to get the image i'll do something in code like (pseudo code):

```
if iPhone5 {
    return mypicture-320
}
else if iPhone6 {
    return mypicture-375
}
else if iPhone6Plus {
    return mypicture-414
}
```

This feels wrong, like there should be a better way by now using only xcassets. Am I missing something?

Related question: If I chose not to use vectors then I'll need the following images:

- **Name**: mypicture-320  **Scale**:@2 **ActualSize**: 640 x 1136
- **Name**: mypicture-375  **Scale**:@2 **ActualSize**: 750 x 1334
- **Name**: mypicture-414  **Scale**:@3 **ActualSize**: 1242 x 2208

Calling them in the same way as described earlier.

Comment: This makes no sense. If you have a vector image, you don't _need_ three different images. You just need _one_ image. That is the whole _point_ of vector images.

Comment: @matt and what would the size of that vector be? iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 have two different sizes with scale @2

Comment: You may want to change your wording from _size_ to _ratio_, as vector images are size-independent.

Comment: @Cœur vectors in iOS are via PDF which does have a size and should be the size at scale "@1". Thats how xcode determines that size of png's to generate

Comment: "and what would the size of that vector be" Whatever size you set the containing image view to. And you have already said that it is "full screen". This is exactly the same as for normal PNG images. You don't have multiple PNG images for multiple screen _sizes_; you have one size in the correct resolution, and it is automatically sized down to fit the image view. Indeed, one might argue that your use of "vector" is just a red herring here.

Comment: @matt just to be clear i'm talking about a PDF vector in xcassets. They needs dimensions at scale "@1", and then xcode generates the necessary pngs based off that. The "fullscreen" container will change aspect ratio and size based on different phones. One size does not fit all

Comment: Clearly one image cannot come in multiple aspect ratios. But in real life we just devise our images so that that doesn't matter.

Comment: @matt basically saying make the image such that it is expected on different screen sizes it will be clipped which is a workaround and not the question I'm asking. What if its an image of a frame and you need the edges to match exactly and not be clipped

Comment: Then use a "resizable" image that stretches / tiles its edges to fit any size. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @matt but then we'll get stretching.. circles going to start looking like ovals :S

Comment: Then change your design so that you won't. You have to think how to accommodate the varying screen sizes / ratios _without_ trying to cover every possibility individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does one handle full screen sized images on on different phone sizes?

By putting a full sized image *view* on the different phone sizes. Constraints tie the edges of the image view to the edges of the screen (in effect), so that it fills the screen no matter how big the screen is. And use of the correct content mode causes the contained image to be resized to match.

If you need the image to stretch/tile in some special way so that it *always* fills the screen exactly, use a [resizable image](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624127-resizableimage). With an asset catalog, you can configure this even more powerfully using Slicing than you can in code. For example, the screenshots below show an iPhone 4s and an iPhone 7; the image fills the screen on both, despite the great difference in size and aspect ratio.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this would cause clipping though as iphone5 and iphone6 have different aspect ratios

Comment: It _might_ not cause clipping. You could use aspect fit instead of aspect fill. But, as I said in my comment, it is trivially obvious that one image cannot of itself have the aspect ratio of every situation in which you will find yourself. However, you will _never_ successfully cover all the aspect ratios by trying to supply multiple images; it isn't what Apple intends you to do, and it isn't worth doing. After all, if your app runs on iPad, with splitscreen multitasking, your "screen" aspect ratio can range from 1:1 to an amazing 1:3!

Comment: Added screen shots to show the result of using a resizable image.

Comment: I'm going to give this one to you, just played around with this and as far as i can tell if any warping is happening its not noticeable by the eye between iPhone5 and higher screens probably due to as @Cœur mentioned all aspect ratios being the same. This will make things easier for sure

Comment: It helps to keep things in perspective. You're making an iPhone app, not the Mona Lisa. :)

Answer (score 1):

320 x 568, 375 x 667 and 414 x 736 all have the same ratio of 9:16.

So you can make one vector image of 9 x 16 at @1x and it will be fine.

Comment: I agree but what would the "@1x" size be? because when xocde generates the "@2x" for iPhone5 it needs to make an image sized 640 x 1136 while for iPhone6 it needs to make 750 x 1334. As far as i understand though it generates the sizes based off a multiple of the "@1x" size

Comment: @pflous you should see for yourself with a simple vector image at 9x16.

Comment: Intending to try this as soon as i get access to photoshop